# Improve the off-topic closure reasons

Tags: discussion, off-topic, close-reasons

Currently, there are only two off-topic closure reasons besides belonging on a different SE site. They are

> Questions on Muslim culture or behaviour unrelated to the teachings of Islam are off-topic here.

and

> Questions on politics are off-topic as they're rarely productive or relevant to the teachings of Islam

I often find a variety of questions that I want to flag as off-topic, but none of the off-topic closure reasons match. For example, I think that questions asking for a practical ruling about specific circumstances should be off-topic is too narrow.

Furthermore, I think that there should be an "Other" option so that the person voting to close can specify why he/she thinks that the question is off topic.

Comment: See also: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/744/22

Answer (score 1):

### Inre "practical ruling" questions being off-topic

I feel that such questions are low-quality, but that's more because we haven't quite found the right balance between "too general" and "too specific" to make them constructive; I disagree that such questions are fundamentally *off-topic* for this site.

The issue is probably complex enough to warrant a whole meta discussion on its own.

### Inre "other" close reason

There already *is* an "other" close reason, but it's only available for users who are actually casting close votes (which requires 500 rep on beta sites).  Such an option is not available to those low-rep users who can only flag a closeable post for review but can't cast actual close votes themselves.

There are [pending feature requests on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188106/better-flagging-as-off-topic) to include a default off-topic reason for flaggers, but I don't know that any progress has been made on that.